# How to specify the relative path in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my project structure

```
Project 
       |__ Services
                  |__ src
                        |__ library
                        |         |__ FTP
                        |         |     |__ __init__.py
                        |         |     |__ FTPHelper.py
                        |         |__ __init__.py
                        |
                        |__ service_1
                                   |__ FTPInteracter.py
                                   |__ Main.py
```

And I want to import FTPHelper in my FTPInteracter

In **FTPInteracter.py**

```
from ..library.FTP.FTPHelper import FTPHelper
```

and I get a **Attempted relative import beyond top-level package** error, how can I fix it using relative import ?

Comment: Is `service_1` missing an `__init__.py`?

Comment: @bbayles that is a good point, but I design to add service_2, service_3, in the same directory in library so they can reuse the library package. So I think service_1 should not be a package.